# struggle to understand toValue, byValue of CABasicAnimation, ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am learning a different way to create a custom indicator. Below is a partial code from tutorial using CABasicAnimation to achieve a task.

```
-(void)spin
{
    CABasicAnimation *spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    spinAnimation.toValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2*M_PI];
    spinAnimation.duration          = self.animationDuration;
    spinAnimation.delegate          = self;
    [self.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];
}
```

What is the *toValue* at line number 2 and what it is used for. When I tried to use

> spinAnimation.byValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2*M_PI];

I dont get the idea of these interpolation values.Was searching over the internet but cant still get the whole picture of it..
Please help if you have any ideas about it. All comments are appreciated.

Comment: To and By are kind of range. ForEg: if you make use of animation for "Opacity" then it could possibly lie between 0.0 to 1.0 (to display an animation for an effect similar to fade in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CABasicAnimations can be a little tough to wrap your head around, but the properties associated with the animation really aren't that tough, once you can visualize what they're trying to accomplish.  For instance, if I have a red square that represents a layer, and I want to rotate it 360˚ (as you're doing there), then I have to initialize an animation object, tell it what I want to animate, and where I want the animation to go.

The animation you've provided mutates a CALayer's internal matrix so that it is rotated to a given value (in this case, `2 * M_PI`, or 360˚) from it's current position (because you haven't specified a `fromValue`) over the given duration.  A given by value tells the animation that over the given period of time, you want the animation to interpolate (or move) **by** the given value for the provided duration (for instance, you could chunk the animation into 45˚ "blocks" by specifying a `byValue` of `@(M_PI/2)`).  The default byValue is a division of the difference of the `toValue` and `fromValue` over the duration of the animation such that the animation is smooth and continuous.

[image]

So, you can think about the animation as going **from** the layer's initial rotational **value**, **to** the layer's new rotational **value**, **by** interpolating a given amount or **value** for a period of time.

Comment: very clear explanation . you just saved me a day . By the way, can you give me the reference for above image.

Comment: @ttran I drew it up in powerpoint...  You can save it to your desktop for future reference, or copy the imgur link to the pic straight from SO, though

Comment: very quick question, for this rotation, I think I should add **spinAnimation.fromValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];** before **spinAnimation.toValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2*M_PI];**. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Test it out.  I would omit the fromValue to keep things implicit.  Core animation should know what to do.

Comment: I tried an animation using :  byValue =  NSNumber(double: M_PI / 4.0) and toValue = NSNumber(double: M_PI * 2.0). 

I expected it to animate in 8 chunks, but it just interpolates smoothly. I also set a duration, but nothing else on the animation object. What is wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You can comprehend "byValue" its means plus the value in original.

Comment: It's a bit more nuanced than that. `byValue` on its own interpolates between the current presentation value and that value plus `byValue`. `byValue` together with `fromValue` interpolates between `fromValue` and (`fromValue` + `byValue`). `byValue` together with `toValue` interpolate between `(toValue - byValue)` and `toValue`. See [**Setting Interpolation Values** in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation#1668446).